# Reference external stylesheet in component from path stored in Angular environment variables

Tags: angular

I've built a service that generates a CSS file.  I want to import the generated CSS into my component.  In theory, I should be able to reference it in

```
@Component({...,styleUrls:[...,'http://where.it.lives/']})
```

Unfortunately, where it lives is defined in my angular build environment.  So it needs to look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: ...,
  templateUrl: ...,
  styleUrls: [ ..., `http://${environment.server.hostname}:${environment.server.port}/path/to/css/file` ]
})
```

Sadly, this doesn't work.  It complains that it can't resolve it.  From looking at the output on the console, the expression is clearly not being evaluated.  The loader is taking the expression and treating it as a string and trying to load that, without any variable expansion.

So, clearly, I can't do it that way.  So how can I do it?  Or can I?

Comment: Use a relative path which shouldn't be different in different environments

Comment: @Mehdi - It's not a file.  It's a service.  It's a full URL, complete with hostname and port.  Using a relative path is not an option.  It lives outside of the Angular build environment.  That's why I have the environment variable to begin with: to tell my application how to get to its API.

Comment: It is a standard 3-tiered application - the UI, the API, and the DB.  The API is served at a different URL than the UI, which changes from environment to environment.  The CSS is being generated in the API, which is why I need to reference the angular build `environment` variable when constructing the URL.